# HTTPS библиотека для Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите HTTPS библиотеку для Android. Чтобы можно было посмотреть как формируются заголовки и тело пакета. Хочу наглядно посмотреть в дебагере что уходит на сервер. Пробую на телефоне продебажить, но он не пускает в классы где все формируется.

Comment: Используйте Retrofit 2